# Where can I find more information on how org custom agenda "type of search" arguments work?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to know the syntax of creating a Custom Agenda Command in emacs org mode.

I found [this tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) on the org mode website. It says that the third argument to a list item in `org-agenda-custom-commands` is:

> Type of search

> The desired agenda display/search. The options include agenda, todo, search, tags, alltodo, tags-todo, todo-tree, tags-tree, occur-tree, or a user-defined function.

There's some bits of information about these options sprinkled throughout the tutorial, but nothing definitive.

I checked the [Custom Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html) section of the org documentation, and its children, but didn't even find the options listed.

I haven't read every page in the [org documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html), but I've looked through any I thought would be relevant to my question. I also searched on google generally, and with `site:orgmode.org`, but I haven't found any sources that outline exactly what how `todo` `search` `tags` `tags-todo` etc work.

Is this written somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it. In the [Storing searches](https://orgmode.org/manual/Storing-searches.html) section of the Org manual, you can find explanations of some, but not all *type* options. I copied the explanations with some minor changes below for the sake of a self-contained answer:

agenda

as a global search for agenda entries planned this week/day.

agenda*

as the same search, but only for entries with an hour specification like `[h]h:mm`—think of them as appointments.

todo

as a global search for TODO entries with TODO keyword specified in the `match` option.

todo-tree

as the same search, but only in the current buffer and displaying the results as a sparse tree.

tags

as a global tags search for headlines tagged as defined in the `match` option.

tags-todo

The same search, but limiting it to headlines that are also TODO items.

tags-tree

as the same search, but only in the current buffer and displaying the result as a sparse tree.

occur-tree

to create a sparse tree (again, current buffer only) with all entries matching the regular expression specified in the `match` option.

For the full list of command types, you have to look at the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable documentation (do `C-h v org-agenda-custom commands` to get that documentation). Below is a snippet of it concerning the `type` option. Note that types listed here not mentioned in the manual are `search`, `alltodo`, `stuck` and *a user-defined function*.

```
type     The command type, any of the following symbols:
          agenda      The daily/weekly agenda.
          agenda*     Appointments for current week/day.
          todo        Entries with a specific TODO keyword, in all agenda files.
          search      Entries containing search words entry or headline.
          tags        Tags/Property/TODO match in all agenda files.
          tags-todo   Tags/P/T match in all agenda files, TODO entries only.
          todo-tree   Sparse tree of specific TODO keyword in *current* file.
          tags-tree   Sparse tree with all tags matches in *current* file.
          occur-tree  Occur sparse tree for *current* file.
          alltodo     The global TODO list.
          stuck       Stuck projects.
          ...         A user-defined function.
```

You might be also wondering how to specify tags in the `match` option. You can find more information about that in the [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html) section of the Org manual.

Comment: Ah! I should have realized it'd be "self documenting" somehow in emacs. Thanks for that. Your answer may now be the canonical resource on www for this...